# My internet provider is limiting my download speed but not browsing speed, How can I overcome that?

Tags: networking, performance, speed

I'm connecting to internet through ppp connection which gives me a speed of ~ 1 mB/s for browsing and a speed of exact (no less or more) 50 kB/s for downloading. but when using socks server (Tor), it gives me more "download" speed (~ 100 kB/s)

so my question is, How my internet provider limit my download speed? is it by limiting speeds of of all ports except 80(http), monitoring the http headers, monitoring at specific OSI layer or what...? what's the difference between downloading a file and browsing which also downloading pages?

AND

How i can download with the full speed? can i make anything local in my computer (i'm using linux) like proxy, ssh tunnel, port forwarding...? Regarding SSH Tunneling: i can't connect to remote server, i don't have one(of course, except Tor, but i need the full speed)

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is, but with regards to Tor, performance will be severely limited due to how the technology is designed. More on this via this link - https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#thesolution

Answer (score 3):

> How my internet provider limit my download speed?

They use Deep Packet Inspection.

> is it by limiting speeds of of all ports except 80(http), monitoring
>   the http headers, monitoring at specific OSI layer or what...?

It could be doing a great deal of things you will have to verify what sort of filtering your ISP is doing yourself.

> what's the difference between downloading a file and browsing which
>   also downloading pages?

A webpage is 1/10 of the size of a file.

> How i can download with the full speed?

You can use a VPN or get a different ISP that doesn't use filter your downloads.

Besides using a differnt connection you don't have a lot of options.

Comment: A VPN won't work when the filtering is whitelisting (boost HTTP traffic throughput) instead of blacklisting (throttle specific non-HTTP downloads).

Comment: @MSalters - Its not clear what the ISP is doing exactly. The author's listed speed is 10 times faster then the fastest speed he was able to achieve ( 1gB/sec vs 100 mB/sec ). The traffic between a VPN and a client is encrypted, the same cannot be said, between an Apache server and a client.

Comment: Actually, 10.000x faster - giga versus kilo. And the encryption is precisely why blacklisting versus whitelisting matters. Anything unrecognized will get the default treatment, and (real) encryption by definition is unrecognized.

Comment: @MSalters - I thought it was faster then 10 times, the point of that statement, was to point out the author unlikely has a 1gB/sec internet connection.  You are right if any traffic that isn't HTTP traffic is being filtered then the only solution is a new provider.

Comment: my bad, it's 1 mB/s, corrected

Comment: it's also giving me the full speed when downloading direct http links, is it still Deep Packet Inspection?

Comment: @TitoTito When I talk about Deep Packet Inspection. Your ISP is inspected EVERY SINGLE PACKET for to see if it matches a specifc type of data. When you visit a website data is sent both ways, this type of data, is easy to detect and is always the same when using a given browser.  You don't indicate what type of activity you notice the decrease on, DPI normally is limited to prevent Peer to Peer traffic, and other similar services.